# Recursive structure (binary tree): obtain values via struct pointer from inside function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm on a mission to implement a basic binary tree. Nodes of the tree are structures holding three fields, an integer value and pointers to the left and right children:

```
typedef struct node {
    int    value;
    struct node *child_left;
    struct node *child_right;
} node;
```

A new node structure is initialised as:

```
node node_init(int value, node *child_left, node *child_right) {
    node   k = {value, child_left, child_right};
    return k;
}
```

A function to store a value inside a left child of the parent node:

```
int insert_left(node *t, int value) {

    node k = node_init(value, NULL, NULL);

    if (t->child_left == NULL) {
        t->child_left = &k;
    }
    else {
        k.child_left  =  t->child_left;
        t->child_left = &k;
    }
}
```

A function to print out value of a left child (This is where the problem is):

```
int node_print(node k) {
    printf("%d", k.child_left->value);
}
```

Main function to test the basic binary tree:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    node root  = node_init(7, NULL, NULL);

    insert_left(&root, 3);
    printf("%d\n", root.child_left->value);
    node_print(root);
}
```

Running this example a direct call to the `printf()` correctly prints 3 as a value of the left child, but the `node_print()` outputs a value of the address of the pointer, e.g. -406140704.

This may be a common and ubiquitous problem, but how do I correctly access the `value` field from inside of the `node_print()` function? If possible, please direct me to some explanatory reading.

Comment: `node   k` is a __local__ variable. It is not available anymore once the function returns! Use `malloc`.

Comment: If you are at a level that you are able to implement binary trees, you should know by now that non static local variables are destroyed after the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your init function uses a local variable which is not available anymore once the function returns. Change it to:

```
node *node_init(int value, node *child_left, node *child_right) {
    node   *k = malloc(sizeof(*k));
    k->value= value;
    k->child_left= child_left;
    k->child_right= child_right;
    return k;
}
```